# MIPS binutils on NixOS?

Tags: mips, nix, nixos, binutils

I'm wondering if there is an existing NixOS package for the MIPS binutils toolchain? In other words, on Ubuntu I would run: `sudo apt install binutils-mips-linux-gnu`, but how do I get tools like `mips64-linux-gnu-ld` and `mips64-linux-gnu-gcc` in NixOS?

I've used https://search.nixos.org/packages to search for packages, but didn't find any that looked right. Does the MIPS compiler toolchain simply not exist for NixOS?

For context: I'm attempting to compile the sm64 decomp on Replit, and I've posted more details relating to my issue in their forum: https://ask.replit.com/t/installing-the-mips-binutils-toolchain/42490

Comment: You might also want to check the [chat room](https://app.element.io/#/room/#nix:nixos.org).